# How to specify a test account for the Instagram Basic Display API App Review

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a webapp that wants to access a user's posts via the new Instagram Basic Display API. Everything works and I now want to go live, but I find the App Review process really hard to understand!

The App Review documentation states that you have to demonstrate in a screencast how the reviewer can log in to your app, request authentication from Instagram and then make use of the Basic Display API. I have created a test account in my webapp and provided those credentials to the app reviewers. The question is what Instagram account they are meant to connect to.

I would assume that they have their own special Instagram accounts that are pre-approved to all in-development applications. But just in case that wasn't the case, I created an Instagram Account just for this purpose and gave its test credentials to the app reviewers.

My review was just rejected, with the screenshot below given as a reason. Turns out that the reviewers did in fact try to use my test instagram account, but Instagram thought their login attempt was suspicious and wanted to confirm that they really own the account.

What am I meant to do with this? Facebook owns Instagram, and I am trying to get access to Instagram's API, but their Facebook app reviewers don't seem able to test their own Instagram Basic Display API!

The only thing I can think of is giving them access to the test account's webmail so they can unlock their own suspicious login attempt.

Is it ***really*** meant to be this difficult?[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFZ5A.jpg)

Comment: I feel your pain. Our app has been rejected 3 times now and it just seems the accounts the Instagram testers use don't have the right permissions: as soon as we try to read from Graph API using reviewer token, we get: "Application does not have permission for this action" error, even tho all good when we try.

I'm considering creating test account as you, but using a VPN to log in in same geo area as FB to try avoid suspicious login :) 

I've read others getting app reviewed after [6 times](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/217877106033579/)! Basically just potluck :/

Comment: My second attempt was rejected with a screenshot of the login screen of my webapp, with the password field marked as invalid. I counted the number of dots in the password field... Two characters away from the real password. *eye roll*

Comment: Our app got rejected 6 times, until we reached out them to ask for proper clarification.
Turns out, as @emertechie said, that their test users don't have "universal test rights". 
And Facebook test accounts can't be used for creating Instagram test accounts because they always require a phone number.
So they basically recommend you to create a new instagram account, add it as tester and share the user & password with them.
What a shitshow of a company.

Comment: @FrakyDale Thanks for sharing! Can you tell me how to reach their support team? I think it would be much easier if I can just guide them through the flow, but it seems we can only connect each other by sending new reviews. I don't even know if I am still talking to the same person.

Comment: Same here, we're on the 10th submittion. We can login to the test account we supplied them from the reviewers own region (Philippines) but they cannot. We are actually integrating with the Graph API and receiving webhooks for messages, mentions etc. It's been so frustrating to say the least....

Comment: One thing we're going to try, is to use a temporary email address that they'll be able to reset the password for, it's the only thing we can think of.
Direct support claims they've escalated the issue, but so far we've heard nothing back. it's been almost a month of back and forth